# Gulp src ignore part of glob path for recursive copy

Tags: gulp, copy, glob

I would like to copy some openui5 resource files into my output folder from bower packages. They have all a common prefix (openui5-). They all have a subfolder called "resources". I would like to copy that content from that subfolder to one common "resources" folder in my output.

I would like to use a glob to copy them with gulp. For now I have to explicitly give each path

```
['bower_components/openui5-sap.m/resources/**/*',
 'bower_components/openui5-sap.ui.core/resources/**/*',
 'bower_components/openui5-themelib_sap_belize/resources/**/*']
```

I would like to use a pattern like this:

```
'bower_components/openui5-*/resources/**/*'
```

But if I do this, I get the full module name copied, too, so my resource folder looks like this:

```
out/resources/
+ -- openui5-sap.m/resources/...
+ -- openui5-sap.ui.core/resources/...
+ -- openui5-themelib_sap_belize/resources/...
```

As I came to understand this is because per default gulp.src takes the first glob (which is in the module name) and makes the recursive structure from there.

Is there a way to ignore parts of the glob pattern for the output or trim the output paths using another glob?

I played around and searched for any solutions, but I cannot find anything.

gulp-rename seems to flatten the whole hierarchy:

```
gulp.task('copyui5resources', function() {
    gulp.src('bower_components/openui5-*/**/*')
        .pipe(rename({ dirname: '' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('out/resources'));
});
```

And using the base option does not help either. It seems to copy just a part of it:

```
gulp.task('copyui5resources', function() {
    gulp.src('bower_components/openui5-*/**/*', {base: 'bower_components/openui5-*'})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('out/resources'));
});
```

Here is a screenshot with my input folder structure and my gulp task so far. Thank you for your help!

[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track trying to use `gulp-rename`. However the `dirname` option isn't powerful enough for what you're trying to accomplish, since it can only replace the entire directory structure. You want to replace just a part of it.

For cases like these `gulp-rename` can be supplied with a function, which allows you to alter `dirname` using everything JavaScript has to offer including `string.replace()`.

That means you can do this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('bower_components/openui5-*/resources/**/*')
    .pipe(rename(f => f.dirname = f.dirname.replace(/openui5-.*?\//, '')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('out/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Sven,

I just stumbled on that hint this morning in another post before I read your post :( I removed the first two parts of the path and got the desired result. It has the advantage, that you can skip as many parts you want and the regex solution has the advantage catching even more similar path parts.

For completion: Here is the solution I came up with:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    path = require('path');

gulp.task('copyui5resources', function() {
    gulp.src('bower_components/openui5-*/resources/**/*')
        .pipe(rename(function(p) {
            var nda = p.dirname.split(/[\\\/]/);
            nda.splice(0, 2); 
            p.dirname = nda.length > 0 ? path.join.apply(null, nda) : "";
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('out/resources'));
});
```

I used path to rejoin the paths indipendent from the OS. Splice removes the first two parts with the package name and the resources directory. You have to use path.join.apply, as it flattens the array, otherwise you get an error.